# In visual studio, what is the shortcut key to auto format feature file on windows platform?

Tags: visual-studio, specflow, feature-file

I am using specflow with visual studio. Is there any shortcut key to auto format feature file code.

PLatform: Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 8):

Use `Ctrl+ K+ D` to format on visual studio

Comment: i have been looking for this

Answer (score 0):

> The code formatting in VS Code is:
>
> On Windows Shift + Alt + F On Mac Shift + Option + F On Ubuntu Ctrl +
>   Shift + I
>
> You can use the search functionality in the editor to find other
>   useful commands Ctrl +Shift+ P

Comment: Shift + Alt + F did not work for me. VS2017 on Windows 10.  All it did was open the File menu.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no function to reformat a whole feature file in Visual Studio when you install the SpecFlow VS Extension.